# openvpn client centos7 requires dev >= 3.3.2-5

Tags: openvpn, centos7

I'm trying to install openvpn client on a server in the office running centos 7 using `yum install openvpn` but it errors saying

```
openvpn-2.3.2-2.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: dev >= 3.3.2-5
```

I have no idea how to resolve this.

What is the simplest solution?

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be running CentOS 7, but you have EPEL6's repository configuration. You should be using EPEL7 with CentOS 7. To fix:

```
yum remove epel-release

yum install epel-release
```

If that does not work, try

```
yum clean all
```

then

```
yum install openvpn
```

The latter should work.

Answer (score 2):

yum uses fastestmirror to find your closest repo, but this might be causing you a few issues if you live outside of EU or US.

Try excluding your local repos by excluding the problem TLD in the fastestmirror config: Edit /etc/yum/pluginconf.d/fastestmirror.conf and adjust the following line to whatever your local TLD is (mine was co.za): exclude=.za

And then run:

```
yum remove epel-release

yum install epel-release

yum clean all

yum install openvpn
```

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem I used openvpn-as instead :

```
wget http://swupdate.openvpn.org/as/openvpn-as-2.0.10-CentOS7.x86_64.rpm

rpm -Uvh openvpn-as-2.0.10-CentOS7.x86_64.rpm
```

If your installation was successful, you should see the following (Replace 0.0.0.0 accordingly):

```
The Access Server has been successfully installed in /usr/local/openvpn_as
Configuration log file has been written to /usr/local/openvpn_as/init.log
Please enter "passwd openvpn" to set the initial
administrative password, then login as "openvpn" to continue
configuration here: https://X.X.X.X:943/admin
To reconfigure manually, use the /usr/local/openvpn_as/bin/ovpn-init tool.
```

Access Server web UIs are available here:
Admin  UI: https://X.X.X.X:943/admin
Client UI: https://X.X.X.X:943/

```
# netstat -nlp | grep openvpn
tcp        0      0 X.X.X.X:443    0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN  31065/openvpn-opens 
udp        0      0 X.X.X.X:1194   0.0.0.0:*          31070/openvpn-opens
```

For more information  : www.vultr.com/docs/installing-openvpn-on-centos-7

Comment: Your answer is an alternate, but it's not answering the original question.